# validación de múltiples select dentro de un form

Tags: javascript

buenas mi pregunta es como puedo hacer para validar que los multiples  que se encuentran dentro de una etiqueta form o div no esten vacios o se encuentren en dice 0 ? evitando a si tener que hacer if añidados para cada uno de los  que estan dentro de un formulario ?

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Saludos.

Comment: ¿Se envia por ajax o se hace el submit por php u otro lenguaje?

Comment: @SantiagoRuiz estoy usando php y jquery

Answer (score 0):

**Validación por PHP**

```
function validator($post = []){

    foreach($post as $value){
        if(empty($value)){
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

if(validator($_POST)){
    echo "Campos completos";
} else{
    echo "Todos los campos son obligatorios!";
}
```

**Validación por jQuery**

```
function validator(form) {

    $(form).find('select').each(function(i, el) {
        var value = $(el).val();
        if (value === null || value.length === 0) {
            return false;
        }
    });

    return true;
}

$('#id_del_form').on('submit', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    $form = $(e.target);
    let arrayForm = $form.serializeArray();
    if(validator($form)){
        let action = $form.attr('action');
        $.ajax({
            url: action,
            type: "POST",
            data: arrayForm,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                alert('enviado');
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(xhr);
            }
        });
    } else {
        alert('incompleto');
    }

    return false;
});
```